# Why is my object not continuously rotating with button press?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a space ship that will rotate clockwise or counter-clockwise depending on if the left or right button is pressed. I was using a virtual joystick and it was working fine but decided to change to left and right buttons. Now if click a button it will rotate to a fix position and stop each time i press the button, I'd like for it to move continuously in one direction while button held down and stop when released.

I'm using the unity standard assets with the cross platform input ButtonHadler script in conjunction with my "move" script.

```
void Update()
{   
    if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("turn"))
    {
       TurnShip();           
    }       
}

public void TurnShip()
{            
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * 50f * Time.deltaTime);        
}
```

Comment: Update: I ended up removing my scripts and added them back and now my ship rotates with out pressing a button. I'm also setting up my buttons thru the Event Trigger (Script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `GetButtonDown`, which returns true only ***once*** when you press the button, and remains false until you release the button and press it again. Use `GetButton` instead.

Comment: I changed to GetButton but now it doesn't move.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to GetButton was part of what I was missing but I had also set up my buttons up incorrectly I had accidentally added one event type with two function a pointer down and pointer up in the same event type instead of separating them.